# Communication layer between client and server

Tags: c#, asp.net, client-server, communication

I'd like to know if there is any technology to control communications between the client and the server in a web application (ASP.NET)

Example:

- Number of requests
- Check that no repeat a request
- Check that an operation was performed

WorkFlow

1. The client sends the request "A"
2. The server receives the request "A", and responds
3. The server marks the request "A" as answered
4. The client resends the request "A"
5. The server answers that the request "A" was answered

Comment: With _client_...do you mean the web browser?

Comment: Hi Adriano! Yes, I refer to the browser :)

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks Steve. I updated the question. I added the workflow (as an example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any ASP.NET application you can use the HttpApplication events to track the needed changes. For example, you could track it using the BeginRequest and/or EndRequest events:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(MyGlobalFlags.TrackingRequests){
        //  do stuff
    }
}

protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(MyGlobalFlags.TrackingRequests){
        //  do stuff
    }
}
```

By personal opinion, I would use a globlal flag that I could turn off easily if I wanted.

If you are talking about an ASP.NET MVC application, I would also recommend using [ActionFilters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470536%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the actions you want to track. You could implement your own ActionFilter class and track those changes OnActionExecuted and/or OnResultExecuted. I would still use the global flag to turn off the tracking without changing code.

```
public class MyTrackingActionFilter: ActionFilterAttribute{
    public override OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
           if(MyGlobalFlags.TrackingRequests){
            //  do stuff
        }
    }

    public override OnResultExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
           if(MyGlobalFlags.TrackingRequests){
            //  do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

As a note, I wouldn't try to do heavy stuff in these events. If the track requires heavy database manipulation that can run in parallel, I recommend you to use a queue system while using the thread pool.

Answer (score 2):

You could intercept the request in the following method, in the `Global.asax` file:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var request = ((System.Web.HttpApplication)(sender)).Context.Request;
        //here you can evaluate and take decisions about the request
    }
```